# $(document).ready() check slows down IE?

Tags: jquery, performance, internet-explorer

I've been working with a company called [Catchpoint](http://www.catchpoint.com/) to hash out some inconsistencies in our client-side code metrics. They have some events that fire which measure milestones in the page load process. Their provided metrics for us is in IE8.

Now, they claim that the way JQuery determines DOM ready in IE actually **drastically** hurts page performance and that we should avoid it at all costs. I'm aware of what JQuery does with the `doScrollCheck()` method and the 1ms recursive `setTimeout` blast on `documentElement` and it occurred to me that they may have a valid claim.

They said performance is hurt exponentially for every `$(document).ready()` block.

My question is, are their any stats out there to validate this claim, and if so, how would I go about implementing an IE-friendly solution without re-writing the JQuery source for my needs.

Comment: keep in mind that you can always drill down [jQuery Source Code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery) to get some stats on the matter...

Comment: He said he's aware of the doScrollCheck() method and the 1ms recursive setTimeout. He'd likely only know that if he read the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to JSperf, multiple DOM ready functions **really do slow down the page** in all browsers, enough so that I will be refactoring a lot of my own code to accommodate for this new finding. IE is embarrassingly slower, of course, but the test isn't as informative as I'd hoped because it's so much slower even with no DOM ready check. The thing to take away from this is to minimize the use of these DOM ready functions whenever possible.

Results in Chrome:

- **Single $(document).ready()**: 734,811 ops/sec
- **Multiple $(document).ready()'s** *[4 blocks]*: 151,989 ops/sec
- **No $(document).ready()**: 208,965,555 ops/sec

Results in IE8:

- **Single $(document).ready()**: 26,349 ops/sec
- **Multiple $(document).ready()'s** *[4 blocks]*: 5,971 ops/sec
- **No $(document).ready()**: 5,000,159 ops/sec

---

### ***Analyzing these metrics:***

- In Chrome, No DOM ready check takes **0.35%** of the time a DOM ready
  check takes
- In IE, No DOM ready check takes **0.53%** of the time a DOM
  ready check takes

That data alone tells us that the `doScrollCheck()` function **deters performance quite a bit**.

**That being said:**

- Chrome's DOM ready check is **27.98 times faster** than IE's
- On Chrome, doing 4 DOM ready checks is **25.45 times faster** than on IE
- The absence of a DOM ready check is **41.79 times faster** on Chrome than IE

On the surface, this looks hopeless - but if you think about it, the IE page with no DOM ready function was executing over 5 million ops/sec and the single DOM ready function on Chrome was executing less than a million. That tells me if you manage to tell JQuery to use a more friendly `doScrollCheck()` function which, say checks if `documentElement` is scrollable every 100ms instead of every 1ms you might see the page load time more competitive with chrome.

What this benchmark really tells me is that even the `DOMContentLoaded` check is slow as hell - there's no excuse to go from 209 million ops/sec to under a million on Chrome.

http://jsperf.com/docready/3

Comment: I'm not sure whether this really tests what the OP wants to test.  You're testing four function calls to set up four `document.ready()` calls vs one function call to set up one `document.ready()` call.  Duh, four function calls it about 1/4 the speed of one function call.  Whether this is relevant or not in real code depends not on the speed of that single function call overhead, but on how significant that is relative to the overall startup time.  It may be  important or it may not be depending upon how much time the actual startup code takes.

Comment: Plus, I think what the OP wanted to know was whether the time to fire `$(document).ready()` is slow in IE compared to other mechanisms of knowing when the DOM is ready and that is not what you are measuring here.  You are essentially benchmarking the call to `$(document).ready()` itself (which just registers the callback function to be called later) rather than benchmarking when it fires and actually calls the callback.

Comment: He did mention he wanted verification for "They said performance is hurt exponentially for every $(document).ready() block."

Comment: But all you proved is that four function calls is 4x slower than one function call.  You didn't prove whether that's relevant to overall startup time or not.  If overall page startup time is 600ms and the three extra `$(document).ready()` calls are 5ms (which your IE8 timings seem to indicate), then that's less than a 1% slowdown - probably not even relevant and certainly not "exponential" as was proposed.

Comment: See updated analytics of the benchmark - would love to hear your insight. I'm actually really curious about a true answer for this question for a faster DOM ready alternative.

Comment: Where have you actually measured the time to get to the actual domready callback?  I'm only seeing a measure of the time to register the callback in the [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/docready/3) which isn't the more important part of this question.  My test above, on the other hand, measures the time between first script execution and the time until `document.ready()` fires which I think is what we care about.  I don't actually have a real IE8 here so I can't run my script in IE8.

Comment: Yea we need your test run in all browsers a bunch of times to see some actual metrics. I really wish Spoon still had IE's...

Comment: To really test this, we should get it out of jsFiddle too into a vanilla web page so there's no influence by the loading of the jsFiddle chrome windows.  I may post that in the next day or so.

Comment: I found this discussion after noticing a very strange and long stall in IE8.  The culprit was a ready() call.  I have no ready() calls on this page, which caused me to investigate.  The big problem with this issue that you raise is that jQuery calls ready() on itself.  Look around line 1519 in jQuery 1.7.1 and you'll see.  So how am I supposed to not call ready() when it's already being invoked?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script that measures the time between `$(document).ready()` firing and code executing at the end of the body (which is the earliest possible time that you can manipulate the DOM).  You can run it yourself in whatever browsers you want.  The page is here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/dLx4L/.

I've done this one in jsFiddle for convenience, longevity and ease of sharing, but you could probably make a more accurate test if you made a standalone webpage that implemented this same technique (no other frames involved like in the jsFiddle).  In any case, you should be able to get the idea here how you could measure this and put real numbers to it.

Comment: Have you seen the site http://jsperf.com? It is a much better way of doing performance comparisons with javascript.

Comment: @GregL - if you think you can code this test in jsperf, please show us how.  I don't think jsPerf lets you compare the timing of ready events.  It's for measuring the execution timing of a given javascript operation which is not what this question is.  I've used jsPerf many times for the kinds of things it is designed for.

Comment: Okay, cool. You're probably right. Was just checking you were aware of that fantastic resource.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - You are right that it can be done without the timer, but your code assumes `$(document).ready()` is always the last one to fire - I wasn't willing to assume that.  But, I did remove the timer here without making the assumption about firing order: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/dLx4L/.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ah, I see. I've improved your demo a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/k3J9g/ (reduced the number of global variables to one, and placed all the logic inside one expression in order to simplify its usage)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - nicely done.  Yours doesn't tell you which came first (mine shows a pos or neg value depending upon which came first), but otherwise it looks like both give a similar result.

Answer (score 0):

My 2c:

I have seen a lot of web developers put ten million javascript code in the page ... along with the last being the document-ready.

a) Bare in mind that NO USER will, in a perfect world, interact with the web page as soon as it loads (shown); and

b) Still in the perfect world, the user will, most likely, look at the entire page before (even scrolling up and down) making any interaction.

With that perfect scenario in mind, all you should have between the < script type ... >< /script> is the miniminum necessary for the SPLASH of the page and, of course, the document-ready.

Here comes the magic: PUT EVERYTHING ELSE IN A SEPARATE SCRIPT.JS file and load it with getScript in the document-ready:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    ...
    ...
    $.getScript('your-scripts-path/your-script-file-name.js');
});
```

Bare in mind that the $.getScript can, of course, become a callback within one of the dom-ready calls. And, it too, can have callbacks.

Good luck!

Comment: This may generate the fastest time until your basic HTML is displayed, but that is often NOT the goal, nor is it the question being asked here.  The question being asked here is how to get the fastest time until your page initializing javascript is run.  Your technique may actually slow that process down because you load scripts dynamically which doesn't start to load your scripts until AFTER the page has loaded.  If those scripts are needed to initialize the page, then the whole process slows down.